# python pd.read flags up error when running rodeo

Tags: python, pandas

I have looked at the python documentation and so far there is nothing wrong with this code.  However when I run this code on Rodeo IDE, it flags this up as an error, can someone guide me to the right direction or post an answer that solves this issue.

My code:

```
#%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 16)

#LARGE_FIGSIZE = (12, 8)

#C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\dataScience\\pandas_tutorial\\climate_timeseries\\data\\temperatures\\xxxx.txt"

#https://github.com/jonathanrocher/pandas_tutorial/blob/master/climate_timeseries/data/temperatures/GLB.Ts+dSST.txt

giss_temp = pd.read_table("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\dataScience\\pandas_tutorial\\climate_timeseries\\data\\temperatures\\xxxx.txt",sep="\s+",skiprows=7,skipfooter=7,engine="python")

print(giss_temp)
```

My error message:

```
ValueError: Expected 2 fields in line 160, saw 87
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-02b52eb96870> in <module>()
     11 #C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\dataScience\\pandas_tutorial\\climate_timeseries\\data\\temperatures\\xxxx.txt"
     12 #https://github.com/jonathanrocher/pandas_tutorial/blob/master/climate_timeseries/data/temperatures/GLB.Ts+dSST.txt
---> 13 giss_temp = pd.read_table("https://github.com/jonathanrocher/pandas_tutorial/blob/master/climate_timeseries/data/temperatures/GLB.Ts+dSST.txt",sep="\s+",skiprows=7,skipfooter=7,engine="python")
     14 print(giss_temp)
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\rodeo\app-2.5.2\resources\conda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    643                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    644 
--> 645         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    646 
    647     parser_f.__name__ = name
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\rodeo\app-2.5.2\resources\conda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    398         return parser
    399 
--> 400     data = parser.read()
    401     parser.close()
    402     return data
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\rodeo\app-2.5.2\resources\conda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
    936                 raise ValueError('skipfooter not supported for iteration')
    937 
--> 938         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
    939 
    940         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\rodeo\app-2.5.2\resources\conda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, rows)
   1990             content = content[1:]
   1991 
-> 1992         alldata = self._rows_to_cols(content)
   1993         data = self._exclude_implicit_index(alldata)
   1994 
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\rodeo\app-2.5.2\resources\conda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _rows_to_cols(self, content)
   2505             msg = ('Expected %d fields in line %d, saw %d' %
   2506                    (col_len, row_num + 1, zip_len))
-> 2507             raise ValueError(msg)
   2508 
   2509         if self.usecols:
ValueError: Expected 2 fields in line 160, saw 87
>>>  
ClearInterruptRestart
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finished the tour. Done with review and edit. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: Your `read_table()` specifies the separator between fields as `sep="\s+"` (one or more spaces).  Usually when you see an error like that with `read_table()`, it means something isn't right about your chosen separator.  For example, it might be appearing within a given field (e.g. a text field might have spaces in it) as well as between fields.

Comment: Did you see this: `ValueError: Expected 2 fields in line 160, saw 87`? You might want to include that line in the question

Answer (score 1):

You should use raw file URL:

```
In [390]: pd.options.display.max_rows = 10

In [391]: url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonathanrocher/pandas_tutorial/master/climate_timeseries/data/temperatures/GLB.Ts%2BdSST.txt'

In [392]: pd.read_csv(url, skiprows=7, delim_whitespace=True, skipfooter=12, error_bad_lines=False, engine='python')
Out[392]:
     Year  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec   J-D  D-N   DJF   MAM   JJA   SON Year.1
0    1880  -34  -27  -22  -30   -16   -24   -19   -12   -20   -19   -16   -21   -22  ***  ****   -23   -18   -18   1880
1    1881  -13  -16   -2   -3    -3   -27   -12    -8   -18   -23   -28   -18   -14  -14   -17    -3   -15   -23   1881
2    1882    3    4   -2  -24   -20   -32   -27   -11   -11   -25   -25   -37   -17  -16    -4   -15   -23   -20   1882
3    1883  -38  -38  -12  -20   -20    -8    -3   -13   -19   -19   -28   -21   -20  -21   -38   -18    -8   -22   1883
4    1884  -20  -14  -31  -36   -33   -36   -31   -24   -29   -25   -29   -25   -28  -28   -18   -33   -31   -28   1884
..    ...  ...  ...  ...  ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...  ...   ...   ...   ...   ...    ...
137  2011   45   44   57   60    47    54    70    69    52    60    50    48    55   55    45    55    64    54   2011
138  2012   38   43   52   62    71    59    50    56    68    73    69    46    57   57    43    62    55    70   2012
139  2013   62   52   60   48    56    61    53    61    73    61    75    61    60   59    53    55    58    70   2013
140  2014   68   44   71   72    79    62    50    74    81    78    64    74    68   67    58    74    62    74   2014
141  2015   75   80   84   71  ****  ****  ****  ****  ****  ****  ****  ****  ****  ***    76  ****  ****  ****   2015

[142 rows x 20 columns]
```